# Apache NiFi parse JSON and substitute in query

Tags: json, bigdata, apache-nifi, dataflow

I'm a new user in NiFi.
I have to develop a dataflow that read a json, extract some attribute dynamically (based on parameter received) and substitute all key/qqvalue in the query.

I'm explain better:

1. read json like this:

> { k1:{
> database1:a,
> Database2:b},
> K2:{
> Database3:c,
> Database4:d,
> Database6:g,
> }
> }

2. receive a key from http for example mykey=k1
   Extract from Json

   **{ database1:a, Database2:b}**
3. substitute in my query all key with the value from the json

   Create table **${databse1}** .... from **${database2}**

My problem is how can read the correct key dynamically and then substitute all key found in the query?

There is some way to do in NiFi?

Thanks

Comment: It's possible to do almost everything in nifi when it's clear what to do. I can't understand what do you need.

Comment: If i undestrand correctly, you want to get the JSON attributes and create a query based on that attributes, right? There is a processor called `Evaluate Json Path`. In that processor you need to create a new attribute (You can name whatever you want, but try to maintain a pattern to facilitate your work) and the value of that attribute is the path to your JSON information. So, if you want to get the `database` attribute, you can get by using the following expression: `$.database1` and so on. I can post a more detailed answer, but it would be nice if you give us more details.